# Can gulp-usemin accept multiple files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, gulp

I have an issue with usemin and am not sure if it is a bug.

My application structure is simple:

```
- root
    |- gulpfile.js
    |- app
    |   |- index.html
    |   |- about.html
    |   |- contact.html
    |   |- js
    |       |- a.js
    |       |- b.js
    |       |- c.js
    |       |- d.js
    |       |- e.js
    |
    |- dist
```

Each of my html files has a usemin block in it to include all of the scripts for example:

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<script src="../js/a.js"></script>
<script src="../js/b.js"></script>
<script src="../js/c.js"></script>
<script src="../js/d.js"></script>
<script src="../js/e.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

When I run the following task:

```
gulp.task('usemin'. function() {
    gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(usemin({
            assetDir: 'app/**/'
        }))
        .pipe(dest('dist/'))
});
```

only the first html file will copy to the new directory, the js in this case is concatenated as expected.

When I change the `gulp.src` to `gulp.src(['index.html','about.html','contact.html'])` I get a diffrent issue, all the html files copy over but only the first one in alphabetical order runs the usemin block replacing the 5 scripts with the new script.

Any insights would be great, I have extensively read through the gulp documentation and the gulp-usemin documentation and can't find any reasons why this should be happening.

The example on the NPM website for the first of my two cases is even given as an example, not sure whats going on here? Maybe something to do with where I am running the gulpfile from?

Is this even possible?

Cheers.

EDIT:
Not sure what was happening here but I created a totally new project and built/ installed the npm plugins and scripts from scratch and everything worked. Not a great solution but it saved me some time.

Comment: Well, you are at least missing an ending quote in assetDir: 'app/**/. Also, borrowing from the gulp-usemin GitHub page: "Alternate root path for assets". So maybe it should be "app/"?

Comment: @juunas this is psudo code, but thanks ill correct that. My extra assests in this example are in app/js so I need to specify that they are in a subdirectory of app not in the same as the .html files.

Comment: After checking the [code](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin/blob/master/lib/blocksBuilder.js#L39), app/** will probably not work as it gets plugged in to [path.resolve](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to).

Comment: I'm also curious why you set it like this: <script src="../js/a.js"></script> instead of src="js/a.js" like in the examples?

Comment: The example can also run with the app directory being the root of the web server, this is for development purposes. When the project is built it will run the usemin to minify everything to the dist directory. @juunas

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I ended up using a different method, this didn't seem to be the best plugin for my uses. It seems to me like a limitation of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `gulp-usemin` just override the main file to use inside your `bower.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.9",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.9",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "angular": {
      "main": "angular.min.js"
    },
    "angular-animate": {
      "main": "angular-animate.min.js"
    },
    "angular-ui-router": {
      "main": "release/angular-ui-router.min.js"
    }
  }
}
```